# How to stop apache2 on ubuntu - no process visible

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and apache2. The default config page shows up even if I stop apache2. This is absolutly strange as there is no process httpd. The server keeps serving the default file and altering the file shows the changes.

This is the output on console:

```
user@rex:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
[ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
user@rex:~$ ps -ef | grep httpd
user      1855  1642  0 16:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
user@rex:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-01-19 16:03:20 CET; 44s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1785 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1768 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1768]:  *
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1785]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex apache2[1785]:  *
Jan 19 16:03:20 rex systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jan 19 16:03:46 rex systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/search?q=%2898%29Address+already+in+use%3A+AH00072%3A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, apache process on Ubuntu is named `apache2` not `httpd` as in CentOS. So, you need to verify it is stopped using:

```
$ ps -ef | grep apache
```

Also, you need to confirm that no process is listening on port 80 using:

```
$ sudo netstat -lntp | grep 80
```

Another thing to confirm, look at apache2 access log to verify you are hitting this machine not any other one `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: thank you. actually there was nginx running on 80. stoped nginx, case solved.